# What does the MySQL error "No database selected" mean?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am running this command:

```
INSERT INTO `db_bibliotecaonline`,`utenti`
    (Nome,Cognome,Data_nascita,Citta,Indirizzo,Cap,Telefono,Email) 
    VALUES('GINO','FRAE','2018-06-13','vaticano','VIA REMO2','01100','3285622478','FRE@TRE.IT');
```

I am getting this error:

> No database selected

Comment: If it's so urgent, you'd think you'd write a better question so you'd get help faster.

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: '*No database selected*' - Select a database.

Comment: have you created a connection before executing the query ? It would be helpful if you post your code not just the error.

Comment: $database='db_bibliotecaonline';

Answer (score 1):

Try dot instead of comma between the database name and the table name:

```
INSERT INTO db_bibliotecaonline.utenti(Nome,Cognome,Data_nascita,Citta,Indirizzo,Cap,Telefono,Email) 
    VALUES('GINO','FRAE','2018-06-13','vaticano','VIA REMO2','01100','3285622478','FRE@TRE.IT')
```

Comment: OK I'ill try thanks

Comment: INSERT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'utenti' tells me this

Comment: I think you may not have permission to write in the database

Comment: strange thing why?

Comment: It may be read-only. Also here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp I found that it may be cause by a misspelling. Can you try running command `use db_bibliotecaonline`? If it gives an error "Database does not exist" then it's misspelled. If there's no error, it's probably read-only.